# How do i check if i'm on the last record of an ADO Recordset?

Tags: loops, asp-classic, do-while

how do i know if i'm on the last record of the recordset.  my loop is as follows;

```
<%do while (adoRsTrade.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent) and (not adoRsTrade.EOF)
NewRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")%>
```

i have a lot of code in between but this if statement is what matters, it displays subtotals of the data being presented as long as the CurRep <> NewRep which means that is is now onto the next persons set of data

```
if (CurRep <> NewRep or FirstTime="T" and (not adorsTrade.BOF)) then
  If FirstTime <> "T" then%>
      <TR>
        <td>
            <table class='FontStandardMinus1' border=0 cellPadding=0 align='left' cellSpacing=0 width="100%" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
                 <TR>
                    <td width="59%" align="left"><b>SubTotals<!-- for <%Response.Write(CurRep) %>-->:</b></td>
                    <td width="10%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totPrincipal,2)%></td>
                    <td width="7%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totInterest,2)%></td>
                    <td width="7%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totCommission,2)%></td>
                    <td width="5%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totSECFee,2)%></td>
                    <td width="4%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totSvcFee,2)%></td>
                    <td width="9%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totNet,2)%></td>
                </TR>
            </table>
        </td>
    </TR>
<%end if%>
```

basically i need another condition that says if currep <> newrep or firsttime="t"
OR if it's the last record in the ADO Recordset then display this is a subtotal as well.

```
<%

FirstTime="F"
CurRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")
adoRsTrade.MoveNext

loop%>
```

any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you in advance,
NickG

Comment: You could store the RecordCountin a variable `rsCount=AdorsTrade.RecordCount` (don't forget to use `adodb.CursorLocation = 3`) and then compare it with a simple variable you incremented in the loop (`aktCount = aktCount + 1`). Something like `If rsCount = aktCount Then`.

Answer (score 8):

You could check for EOF after you call MoveNext on your recordset to test if you are on the last record.

For example:

```vbs
Do While adoRsTrade.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent And Not adoRsTrade.EOF
  ' DO SOME STUFF
  ' --------------
  ' --------------
  adoRsTrade.MoveNext
  If adoRsTrade.EOF Then
    ' last record!
    ' DO SOME OTHER STUFF
  End If
Loop
```